# Understanding the Lambert W function

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, exponentiation, lambert-w, exponential-diophantine-equations

I am asking this question because I wish to get a feel for how it would be to *invent* the Lambert W function. I would like to really understand it.

We have the equation:
$$xe^x=y \tag{1}$$
and we want to find **all** the **real** solution of it.

Of course nowadays we know that the solutions are: $x=W_k(y)$ and that, to be more specific, in $\mathbb{R}$ we only have the branches $k=0$ and $k=-1$.

**But suppose instead that we know nothing about the Lambert function; in searching for solution to (1) how can we "invent" it?** And in particular: what's up with the branches?

I would prefer answer that don't involve heavy mathematical machinery, the simpler the better.

(*Bonus question:* If you like this question and want to extend the discussion I would like to see how the reasoning can be extended to the complex numbers, although I would like to see it *as an extension* and not as the starting point of the answer.)

Comment: The function $y=xe^x$ is strictly monotonic on $[-1,\infty)$, thus injective, and so it has an inverse which we'll call $W_0$. Same goes for $(-\infty,-1]$ and $W_{-1}$.

Comment: The reference to consult for this is: Corless, R. M.; Gonnet, G. H.; Hare, D. E. G.; Jeffrey, D. J.; Knuth, D. E. "On the Lambert W function". *Adv. Comput. Math.* 5 (1996), 329–359.